# FastAPI repository endpoint for version control system

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I am creating an API for a version control system. This is my first time creating an API (and a web project in general) and I wanted to get some feedback. I plan to connect this API to a frontend to create website. I choose to share this part of the code because the rest of the code follows this structure. For reference: Users have repositories ; repositories have commits, files and branches; branches point to a specific commit; commits and files have a many to many relationship.

```
router = APIRouter(prefix= "/{user_name}", tags=["repository"])

@router.post("/", response_model= schemas.RepositoryResponseSchema ,status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_repo(user_name: str, repo_name : str, 
                db: Session = Depends(database.get_db), current_user = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
   
   if current_user.name != user_name:
      raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="User does not have permission to create a repository for another user")
   user = crud.get_one_or_error(db, models.User, name= user_name)
   repo = crud.create_unique_or_error(db, models.Repository, name= repo_name, creator= user)
   master_branch = crud.create_unique_or_error(db, models.Branch, name= "master", head_commit_oid = None, repository_id= repo.id)

   repo.branches.append(master_branch)
   repo.current_branch_id = master_branch.id
   db.commit()
   return repo

@router.put("/{repository_name}/change-branch", response_model=schemas.ChangeBranchResponse, status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def change_branch(user_name: str, repository_name: str, branch_name: str, 
                  db: Session = Depends(database.get_db), current_user = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
   if current_user.name != user_name:
      raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="User does not have permission to change a branch for another user")
   user = crud.get_one_or_error(db, models.User, name= user_name)
   repo = crud.get_one_or_error(db, models.Repository, name= repository_name, creator= user) 
   branch = crud.get_one_or_error(db, models.Branch, name= branch_name, repository_id= repo.id)
   repo.current_branch = branch
   db.commit()
   return schemas.ChangeBranchResponse(repo.name, branch_name=branch.name)

@router.get("/{repository_name}/tree", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def get_tree_for_repo(user_name: str, repository_name: str, db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
   """Return the graph formed by commits and branches
       o  → o  →  o  →  o  →  o → o
            ↓                     ↑
            o ← dev_branch    master_branch 
   """
   user = crud.get_one_or_error(db, models.User, name= user_name)
   repo = crud.get_one_or_error(db, models.Repository, name= repository_name, creator_id= user.id) 
   
   # Create an empty directed graph
   graph = nx.DiGraph()

   for branch in repo.branches:
      head = branch.head_commit_oid
      commit = crud.get_one_or_error(db, models.Commit, oid=head, repository_id= repo.id)
      while commit:
         graph.add_node(commit.oid, label=f"Commit: {commit.commit_message}")

         if commit.parent_oid:
            graph.add_edge(commit.parent_oid, commit.oid)
         else:
            root = commit.oid # Returnning this could be good for drawing better graphs

         commit = crud.get_one_or_none(db, models.Commit, oid=commit.parent_oid, repository_id= repo.id)


   return json_graph.node_link_data(graph)
```

I am unsure with some of my design choices and I am looking for some feedback.

Comment: You're missing a good bit of code to make this complete (imports, other modules, etc). For instance, what is `crud`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## design of URL namespace

```
@router.post("/", ... )
def create_repo( ...
```

This seems like the wrong URI.
Prefer "/{repository_name}".
As stated it seems like we're creating a user.

Also, "lint": prefer
[$ black *.py](https://pypi.org/project/black)
over the idiosyncratic spacing choices found in OP.

## boilerplate

We naturally see these a fair amount in signatures:

```
def ...
        db: Session = Depends(database.get_db),
        current_user = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
   
   if current_user.name != user_name:
      raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="... permission ...")
```

Could an `@authenticated` decorator maybe subsume them?

Import nit: It might be convenient to add aliases like
`from status import HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN`

## conventional branch name

```
   master_branch = crud.create_unique_or_error( ... , name= "master", ... )
```

There are good reasons why GitHub and others
have long ago ditched that name, in favor of `main`.
You might choose similar defaulting.

## insert

```
   repo = crud.create_unique_or_error( ...
   repo.branches.append(master_branch)
```

You chose to omit `import`s and a lot of other essential Review Context.
For example, each import is implicitly a pypi docu-pointer.
Here, I do not know what that last line did.

My fear is that the ORM has a `list` that we tacked the branch onto,
and the DB table has a JSON column containing a list or something
like that.
In other words, that the DB is de-normed.

I encourage you to
[normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form),
to INSERT a separate row for each and every branch.
Later on you'll be glad that you did.
Avoid aggregates such as "list" or "array" columns,
as they make relational queries harder, and harder to optimize.

## backend vs UI

```
def change_branch( ...
```

This is a mapping from "(user, repo)" to "default branch".

It's not obvious to me that the backend has to offer
such a service at all.
It feels more like a frontend UI kind of thing.

And it seems like the UI might have multiple preference settings
to keep track of, beyond just "current branch".

Suppose I merge a pair of branches, big enough that conflict resolution
takes more than a second. Meanwhile I do some other operation
on another branch. Do I need to worry about racing default branch name?
I would expect that each operation would explicitly mention
things like (user, repo, branch), rather than letting branch
default to the current one. The UI does such defaulting, sure,
but not sending explicit branch name to the backend API seems a bit off.

Instead of a branch name,
maybe operations like merge send an unnamed hash to the backend?

## more boilerplate

```
@router.get("/{repository_name}/tree", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

We will want to default that `200`, right?
Possibly with a decorator, or with a souped-up `router` object.

## scaling

```
def get_tree_for_repo( ...   
   graph = nx.DiGraph()

   for branch in repo.branches:
      head = branch.head_commit_oid
      commit = crud.get_one_or_error( ... )
      while commit:
         graph.add_node( ... )
```

For a "hello world" repo I'm sure that's very nice.

You will want to test against realworld historic repos with
a few years of commits in them.
Not linux kernel, but maybe from say an Apache project,
something biggish.

You will soon discover that users will wish to
limit their exploration of the graph to a certain
date range, or the last K commits resulting in a certain tag ID.
Else traversing the graph will take all day.
Your design should bear in mind that some queries
will want to quickly chase digraph arrows in the "opposite" direction.

Also, when reporting on a giant graph,
the `crud.get_one_...` is insanity.
I'm looking at N roundtrips to the DB for N commits.
Figure out how to issue a single giant SELECT ... WHERE ...
so the database backend planner knows you want *everything*.
It will find an appropriate access path,
gather up the result rows, and stream them at you
as fast as TCP can go, rather than doing a stutter stop
next row next row for each of N rows.

## documentation

It's unclear what the various concepts in your VC system are.
So document them, and include URL of documentation in your source code.

Hard way would be to document from scratch.

Easier way would be to stand on the shoulders of giant Linus,
who in turns stands on the shoulders of others.
Write down that your system is "just like git",
or more likely that it is "git lite" and then delineate the limits.